# Convergence of Sequence 3

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Hello I have the following question.

I need to check $a_n = nq^n$ on convergence and if it converges I need to find the limit.

$(-1 < q < 0)$

It seems that the limit is $0$.

I set into the definition:

$|nq^n-0| < \epsilon $

$|q^n| < \frac{\epsilon}{n} $

But my problem is I can't get all $n$ on one side, so I can't find an index $n$.

My guess was $|q^n| < 1$, but I **can't** say that $|q^n| < \frac{\epsilon}{n} < 1 $ or $|q^n| < 1 < \frac{\epsilon}{n}$, if I could say one of these I would be able to estimate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note $|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=|q|\dfrac{(n+1)}{n}\to |q|$ as $n\to\infty$.

Thus there exists $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|< |q|+r$ where $0<r<1$ is so chosen that $|q|+r<1$.

Thus $|a_{n+1}|<|(|q|+r)a_n|$ for all $n>N$ so iterating, $0<|a_{n+1}|<(|q|+r)^{n-N}|a_{N+1}|\to0$

Comment: Ah sorry, I forgot to say (-1 < q < 0). Thank you.

Comment: Then take $r$ such that $0>q+r>-1$ and make some slight modifications to the inequalities. This goes through.

Comment: EDITED, please check

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a little bit problem why I can use here the  ratio test here. Where do I know that $|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| \lt |q| + r$

Comment: I am not using any ratio test, although probably this is the ratio test. See this is just a technique to show convergence. Anyway, to show why the inequality holds, note that if $x_n\to x$ then for large enough $n$, $x_n<x+t$ for any $t>0$, This is a basic result from analysis.

Answer (score 0):

We have $|a_n|^{1/n} \to |q|$. Let $x \in (|q|,1)$. Then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$|a_n|^{1/n} <x$ for all $n>N$.

Thus

$|a_n| <x^n$ for all $n>N$.

This shows: $a_n \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I think it's too complicated for me.